# How can I get the data from an array inside another array that stores values in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have an array and this array has another array inside.
I need to obtain the data inside this other array.

[image: A screenshot of the array structure, featuring a data key, that has a numeric-index-based array. The first element of this sub-array is equal to 11-117995.]

This is the code that I use to get all the array items, but I am not sure how to  get the other array elements that are stored at `index(0)`.

```java
if (msg.equals("warning")) {
    List<String> dataWarn = (ArrayList<String>) data;
    Log.i("api", dataWarn.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please post code, not a link to a picture of some code.

Comment: Why not `data[0][0]`?

Comment: Looks like you actually have `ArrayList`s which would result in a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. Just get the first element from the list twice:

```java
if (msg.equals("warning")) {
    List<String> dataWarn = (List<String>) data;
    List<String> dataWatnItem0 = (List<String>) dataWarn.get(0);
    Log.i("api", dataWatnItem0.get(0).toString());
}
```